# How to search among your Favorites?

Tags: support

How do you perform a search that is limited to your list of *Favorites* questions?

Comment: Queries for all sorts of things can be found at the [Mathematica section of StackExchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/queries).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start the query with

> infavorites:mine

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/searching